# return column index condition on column names

Tags: r

I have a data frame named `dat`. It has some columns with prefix `vix`.

Eg.

`Date, VO, vix2, vix3, vix4, ... vix24, other columns`

In this case,

`start = which(names(dat) == "vix2")`

`end = which(names(dat) == "vix24")`

But the problem is, I don't know the number arrangement after `vix`. In this case, is there a way to return `start` and `end`?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel You can undelete the answer.  I was just curious with your `general appraoch` comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 range(grep('vix', names(dat)))
```

Suppose if the columns are not consecutive

```
  v1 <- c('Date',  'vix2',  'v0', 'vix3', 'V5', 'vix4')
  range(grep('vix', v1))
  #[1] 2 6
```

will give the first and last entry with 'vix', but if you are going to subset the dataset for 'vix' columns, you don't need the `range`, just `grep` will be enough

```
  grep('vix', v1)
 #[1] 2 4 6
```

Comment: It works if the consecutive columns 'vix' are consecutive, which should be implied by the OP, but is not necessarilly the case!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I didn't get your comment. Suppose. `v1 <- c('Date',  'vix2',  'v0', 'vix3', 'V5', 'vix4'); range(grep('vix', v1))#
[1] 2 6`

Comment: in this case it is not clear what happens, the OP is not very explicit about this case!